# Is there a way to Launch The updater.exe file of Guitar pro 6 when running in Wine?

Tags: updates, wine

I have downloaded the windows version of Guitar Pro 6 and it runs in Wine, However when I try to enter my License key, I get the error message "Can't open Updater" and then when I click ok the program shuts down. I have tried to run Guitar pro updater as a separate file but this also fails to open. Has anybody had this problem? if so How did you cure it?

Comment: Why are you not using the Ubuntu version of Guitar Pro?

Comment: Because this linux version fails to launch